# Python 'if' statement - if in [string] == 'string' -- Not working?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to find a letter in a giving string. Here's what I got:

```
 if i in steps == 'u':
    y -= pixels_per_move
elif i in [steps] == 'r':
    x -= pixels_per_move
```

steps is a randomly generated string consisting of u, d, r, l. 
So it's something like 'uuurlluddd'

So i'm just looking for those letters in 'steps' but with the code above I'm getting the error

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not int

Which I don't understand because steps is not an int, and i've tried putting str() around it in multiple places but same error occurs. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `i in steps == 'u'` - what were you even trying to do there? That's not at all how `in` or `==` work.

Comment: And why did you look at `steps` when the error message was talking about the *left* operand of `in`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it is saying is that `i` is an int. You are testing whether `i` is in `steps` which is a string. The mostly likely thing I think you are trying to do is get the `ith` character of the `steps` in which case you should use `if steps[i] == 'u':`

Answer (score 1):

You confuse the `for i in steps` with the `if` statement. Anyway, it should look something like this:

```
for i in steps:
    if i == "u": #here i isn't a int but a string!
        y -= pixels_per_move
    elif i == "r":
        x -= pixels_per_move
```

You could add a `print` statement to print x and y (optional).